# Python argparse - optional argument to be none or more

Tags: python, argparse

I have an optional argument -s to setup the tool. I hope user could give an input or use the default value. If he decides to use the default one, he should be able to skip giving extra input.

for example, `myScript -s` and `myScript -s "Hello"`  should both work

Seems `action = store_true` not working well with nargs='*'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argparse` store action allows the programmer to differentiate 3 use cases:

- option is not present (uses `default`)
- option is present and has no additional value (uses `const`)
- option is present and has a value (uses the passed value)

Assuming that you want `-s` and `-s Hello` to perform the same, you could use

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Some desc.")
parser.add_argument("-s", nargs='?', const='Hello', default = None)
```

then you can test it:

```
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(s=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(["-s"])
Namespace(s='Hello')
>>> parser.parse_args(["-s", 'Hello'])
Namespace(s='Hello')
>>> parser.parse_args(["-s", 'foo'])
Namespace(s='foo')
```

Comment: Appreciate for your help! And one more small question, what is that "default" for?

Comment: @JiekeWei: to identify when the option is not passed at all.

Comment: Thank you so much!